# Windows XP SP3 Cannot delete a randomly generated folder in an external hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I just plugged a Toshiba 1.5 TB External hard drive in and found a new folder that wasn't there the last time. It's titled "311700553bbab72ec1b0" with a subfolder titled "update". I am the owner, therefore the administrator of the computer with full rights, but I cannot access "update" to see what's inside it, nor can I delete it. I was not involved in putting it there, and I don't know where it came from. The hard drive was not plugged in during any recent file installations. When I try to delete it, I get the standard "Access is Denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected, and that the file is not currently in use". Virus scans reported "Scan complete on 0 items", and the folder size is 0 bytes.

How can I delete this folder, and prevent it from doing anything that I don't know about to my computer? And does anybody know where it came from?

Comment: You cannot delete it because its in use by Windows, its being placed in their, because Windows likes using largest hdd to store updates. You can delete it by using another computer.  The folder of course is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

It came from a MicroSoft NET version update. I recently had a similar experience. I was baffled as well. (XP Pro SP3)

FWIW I also received a M$ Update in the meantime which had nothing to do with NET. I went to Add/Remove and repaired NET v3.5, though I also had v4 installed. The odd folder disappeared and the s/w that needed it, which prompted the NET update, functions appropriately fine.